# Error con variable double en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que de una sucesión que sea de la forma 1,10,100,1000,10000,... identifique que numero de la sucesión es 1 y cual es 0. Este es mi programa (estoy ocupando double por que el problema me pide que ocupe numeros de 2 elevado a la 31):

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

bool versi(double);
double sumas[10000] = {1,2},pos = 2;

    int main(){
        versi(1000000);
        unsigned int rep;
        double num; 
        bool *a;
        cin >> rep;
        a = new bool[rep];
        for(int i = 0; i < rep; i++){
            cin>>num;
            a[i] = versi(num);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < rep; i++){
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        return 0;
    }

bool versi(double num){
    int ver;
    if(sumas[pos-1] >= num){
        for(int i = 0; i <= pos; i++){
            if(num == sumas[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }else{
        while(ver < num){
            sumas[pos] =ver= sumas[pos-1]+pos;
            pos++;
        }if(sumas[pos-1] == num ||sumas[pos-2] == num){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando compilo el programa me salta el siguiente error:

```
 [Error] invalid types 'double [10000][double]' for array subscript
```

Comment: Hola. Creo que el problema, entre otros que tendrás que depurar (como por ejemplo usar la variable ver dentro de la función versi sin haberla inicializado nunca y usarla para una comparacion while( ver < num)), es que no puedes usar como índice de un array algo que no sea entero, en tu caso un double. Un double no se usa para enteros largos porque es para representar números no enteros.

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro y autoexplicativo, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> [Error] tipos no válidos 'double [10000][double]' para indizar la formación.
> ```

Te dice que no puedes indizar una formación<sup>1</sup> con un `double`, cambia la variable de indizado por un entero:

```
double sumas[10000] = {1,2}; int pos = 2;
//                           ^^^ <--- Entero.
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o *array* en inglés.